# Нужна помощь в составлении блок схемы

Tags: блок-схема

Задача: Определить номера столбцов матрицы, в которых встречается хотя бы один
отрицательный элемент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кажется, что есть где-то ошибка

Comment: Блок-схемы никто не рисует, кроме безумных преподов. Однако непонятно, как оформлен цикл, и в какой момент добавляется j, и обеспечено ли добавление столбца один раз.

Comment: Похоже, что в блок-схеме не хватает ввода элементов матрицы; также во втором цикле по столбцам есть опечатка в условии.  Вообще, стоило бы во внешнем цикле проходить по столбцам, а во внутреннем -- по строкам, тогда при обнаружении _первого_ отрицательного элемента `A[i][j]` можно было бы сразу завершать внутренний цикл по `break`, чтобы в список `negative_columns` не добавлялись дубликаты.